# sql syntax error when running script

Tags: mysql, error-handling

i have an sql script to run on my database with a user table and an order table. The user table part worked fine, the problem comes when i try to make the foreign key as part of the orders table.

Here is my script:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`order_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Heigth` INT(11),
`Width` INT(11),
`Length` INT(11),
`status` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
foreign key (`id`) references `users`(`id`)
)  ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=LATIN1;

insert into `orders` values
(1, 1, 5, 6 ,7, true),
(2, 2, 234, 234, 4, false);
```

and here is the error i get: 
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
    manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
    syntax to use near ''order_id'),
    foreign key ('id') references `users`('id')
    )  ENGINE=INNODB AU' at line 8
    ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'useradmin.orders' doesn't exist

how come this be? It's auto-generated by mysql workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement shown in the question executes successfully for me, after I did a `CREATE TABLE users (id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=INNODB;`.

The error text seems to indicate that the SQL that was executed differs from the SQL text posted in the question.  In particular, the error message seems to indicate single quote characters, where the posted SQL has backticks.

```
... near ''order_id'), foreign key ('id') references `users` ('id') ) 
          ^        ^                ^  ^                      ^  ^
```

(In MySQL, identifiers are normally escaped with backticks, exactly as shown in the SQL statement in the question. Single quotes are used around string literals.)

Before we go any further with investigation, verify that the statement being executed (and causing the error) is the SQL posted in the question, I mean EXACTLY right down to the last nit-pickin' backtick character.